# Equivalent of Stata tab command in R

Tags: r, command-line, stata, tidyverse

I'm trying to find out what the Stata command `tab x y if z>1` would be in **R**.

Other than `d %>% filter (z>1).`

Comment: Why the "other than" clause? Seems like `d %>% filter(z > 1) %>% count(x, y)` or similar should work

Comment: With questions like this, (1) be accurate with your syntax (you previously had `tab x, y if z > 1` which makes no sense (2) explain what the syntax does any way with a simple example: otherwise you depend on people being fluent in both languages.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments (I will take note of them).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `x`, `y`, and `z` are all variables in a data.frame named `d`, then I believe one way with Base R commands would be:

```
table(d[d$z>1, "x"], d[d$z>1, "y"])
```

Or first subset `d` and call the subset `d2`, then tabulate:

```
d2 <- d[d$z>1, ]
table(d2$x, d2$y)
```

Comment: Or `with(d[d$z > 1, ], table(x, y))`

Comment: Thank you for your answers.